# PBI Create Custom column using Power Query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am very new to `DAX` and `Power Query` in `PBI` and I have started learning them by trying to create a custom column in PBI using Power Query.

The purpose is to add a certain value in a new column `Flight_Cancelled` when there a certain corresponding value in a column `Cancellation`.

Below is my code to achieve this using DAX. Now, I want to do the same using Power Query Editor > Create Custom Column. How can I do this?

DAX code:

```
Flight_Cancelled = SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    Arrivals[Cancellation_Time] = "", "No", "Yes")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power Query, use the ribbon command to add a new column in the Arrivals table, then build an IF statement along the lines of

```
if [Cancellation_Time] = null then "No" else "Yes"
```

The exact formula may need to be changed based on the data type and content of the Cancellation_Time column. Power Query is a typed language, so data type is important, i.e. you cannot compare date with text. If Cancellation_Time is a date, you can check if it equals `null`, i.e. does not have a value

Power Query has a user interface to build new columns with a formula editor where you can double click to insert columns and intellisense to help with functions.

Comment: Cheers for the super quick response :) And yes I had to first to change the datatype of `Cancellation_Time` from `Text` to `Date` in order to show `empty/blank` values as `null`. Then the code in the answer worked.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Yup, I just accepted the answer, the site made me wait for seven minutes before accepting the answer.